# Updating a UIButton value in a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a clash royale like app.
Here's my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584688/how-can-i-change-the-same-value-between-different-view-controllers)
I did like they told me and used a static var, and it worked fine.
Then used this

```
    moneyTopButton.setTitle( "\(AppDelegate.money)", for: .normal )
    disksTopButton.setTitle( "\(AppDelegate.disks)", for: .normal )
```

[image]

And it also worked fine
But now every time I change the money/disks values the button dont update in the tabcontroller tabs (they update everywhere besides that)

how do i fix this?

Comment: Using `AppDelegate.money` and `AppDelegate.disks` seems really bad practice. The AppDelegate's job is mostly related to the application's lifecycle and application logic should not be placed in that file.

Comment: I might be able to help you. Would you mind approving my answer if it solves your problem?